# 320 and up reverts to 320 in ie7+8 standards mode?

Tags: css, html, boilerplate, html5boilerplate

I'm new to the 320 and up template and I'm currently in the process of testing a shell of a site on ie9 but using dev tools to test ie8 & 7 in standards mode.

The site also uses biolerplate html5 and wordpress.
I've looked at and tested what I feel is everything I can see and it all looks like it should work in all browsers... it doesn’t

I've uploaded a test site here:
http://dev.clear-living.co.uk

If anyone can spot the error that my eyes (blearily) fail to see please point it out for me. I've been looking at this for two days now!

UPDATE:
when I say it doesn't work I mean it stays on the 320 width format and doesn't scale up in the browser. Best way of testing this is just to resize the browser window. In the link above this works fine in all browsers except ie7 & 8 in standards mode.

Comment: Could you define "doesn't work" for us? And possibly narrow it down to a postable short example?

Comment: I think I'm just going to strip this right down and start over, leave out Wordpress for now and if I still get the same errors I'll be able to post some simple example code

Comment: Having had a look, I think I see what's happening. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Matt for your comments. Even when I did include respond.js it still wasn't working!
I've spent a long, long time trying to get this to work....

...answer.

I got the latest respond.js from github and it worked like a dream!
Wish I'd have thought about that earlier!

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it, 320 And Up is designed to use responsive media queries in its CSS, which don't work in IE8 and below. There's a script provided with 320 -- [respond.min.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) -- to enable media queries using Javascript in these recalcitrant browsers, but you don't appear to be including it, which I'm guessing is what's causing your problem.

Check the bottom of the example pages provided with 320 And Up; you'll see the script included there, selectively for the more useless versions of IE. DOMAssistantCompressed and selectivizr are also included; I'm guessing you'll want all of those make IE8 and below work with 320 And Up..

Comment: thanks, I did check all the additional js files were there, I'll look again.

Comment: Assuming you've left Respond.js in its own script file, it's definitely not being included under IE8 for me (I just checked, using F12 Developer Tools.)

Comment: You're right, I had them in my local files but not pushed to the online test site. Anyway, they're there now and still not working. Thanks for you help but I think I'll stip it back & start again like I said.

Comment: Thanks to @Matt for your comments, it made me think more in detail about Respond.js and after tweaking the css widths for each of the larger screen sizes it works! 

Now I just need to figure out the right percentage to get my width in pixels back each time!